# Swedish letters in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, character, letter

I have been using Bootstrap for a while now and I mostly write in English.

I would like to import Swedish letters. When I try to get the letters å, ä, ö from google fonts it do not seem to work.

Comment: make sure you set a character set http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do.  First, I would recommend using the proper character set in your HTML by putting something like this in your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="ISO-8859-1" />
```

You can also use HTML encoding for your Swedish characters:

```
&Aring;
&aring;
&Auml;
&auml;
&Ouml;
&ouml;
```

There is also a similar article on Stackoverflow: [Swedish characters and UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365526/swedish-characters-and-utf-8)

Hope this helps.