# What can i do to the question marks?

Tags: html, css

So im working on a website that has the swedish alfabet but whenever i write an åäö it shows as questionmarks. I tried to put utf-8 in  but it dosent change.
[image]

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365526/swedish-characters-and-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

to your html header