# PHP Read and render filenames (with special chars) for download

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters

I have to render a list of files, with link to them. What I have written:

```
$path = "pdf/".$lang."/*";
$fileList = glob($path);

echo "<ul>";
foreach($fileList as $filename){
    $splitted = explode("/", $filename);
    echo '<li><a href="'.$filename.'">'.end($splitted).'</a>'; 
}
echo "</ul>";
```

It works if there are no special chars in the filenames. If there are, a � is rendered.

I changed the code followings:

```
$path = "pdf/".$lang."/";
$fileList = glob($path."*");

echo "<ul>";
foreach($fileList as $entry){
    $splitted = explode("/", $entry);
    $filename = iconv('WINDOWS-1252', 'UTF-8', end($splitted));
    echo '<li><a href="'.$path.$filename.'" target="_blank">'.$filename.'</a>'; 
}
echo "</ul>";
```

this solution works only on the localhost. Once I publish it the special chars are not rendered correctly. Instead of the `ä` it renders `Ã¤`.
How can I solve it?

**Edit:**
This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275411/php-output-showing-little-black-diamonds-with-a-question-mark) question. As I'written above I get Ã¤ not �.

Localhost and server are working on Windows.
PHP Version on localhost is 5.6.35. Server in on 7.1.

Comment: Are you on Windows? What's your PHP version? That was a traditional problem in PHP on Windows but it was fixed on PHP/7.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP output showing little black diamonds with a question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275411/php-output-showing-little-black-diamonds-with-a-question-mark)

Comment: As I've written, It is not showing a black diamond.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the filename is then encoded twice with UTF-8 - what encoding settings are you using on your server / local php?

Comment: Both are on Windows, on localhost PHP is on 5.6.35 and on the server 7.1

Comment: ok :) now I'm pretty sure it is just a double utf encoding - have you tried outputting it without any further encoding on your server?

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely sure but this might be that your file on server gets encoded to ISO-8859-1 instead of utf-8.

please see this question as a ref:
[Swedish characters and UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365526/swedish-characters-and-utf-8/31273640#31273640)

I wrote an answer on this issue, it is the second answer.

Try changing your charset meta-tag to ISO-8859-1

Comment: no, I used the html5 notation for setitng UTF8. However, if this were the problem, shouldn't it behave the same on localost and on the server?

Comment: > However, if this were the problem, shouldn't it behave the same on localost and on the server?   - Probably but not 100%. Might be some server encoding going on somewhere that we forget to think about